# Can't set material for loaded model

Tags: three.js, webgl

May you help me to find out why material don't apply to mesh?

http://websaints.net/model/index2.html — loading model with THREE.MeshNormalMaterial() material — ок.
http://websaints.net/model/index.html — trying to load with texture — not ok.
I create model with makehuman.org, save model as obj and then convert obj to json with help of grunt-three-obj
I think I do everything right … but somewhere I am wrong and get err:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'needsUpdate' of undefined
```

Code:

```
var angle = .05,
    scene = new THREE.Scene(),
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(63, 4/3, 0.1, 1000),
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      canvas: document.getElementById("screen"),
      antialias: true
    }),
    json_loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(),
    model = null

    json_loader.load('http://websaints.net/model/json/human.js', modelLoaded, 'http://websaints.net/model/json/');

    renderer.setSize(600, 400);
    camera.position.x = 0;
    camera.position.y = 0;
    camera.position.z = -10;

    function render() {
      if(model!=null){
        model.rotation.y+=.05;
      }
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
    render();

    function modelLoaded(geometry, materials){
      model = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
      model.position.z = 10;
      model.position.y = -8;
      scene.add(model);
      camera.lookAt({x:0,y:0,z:0});
    }
```

With all best regards. Anton.